# How can I compare time and dates accurately?

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the given time and date not passed yet so I have this:

```js
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var currentTime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                    + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                    + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                    + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                    + currentdate.getSeconds();
    
    
const givenTime = '2021-08-01T16:49:08.678Z';
    
// This is not comparing time , it only compares the dates
console.log(new Date(givenTime) > new Date, currentTime);
```

Unfortunately it seems that the code does not compare the times and it only compares the dates, so two times in the same day return a wrong result:

I mean code returns true if : `const givenTime = '2021-08-01T16:49:08.678Z';` and current date is `" 1/8/2021 @ 18:7:21"`

How can I compare time and dates accurately?

Comment: `givenTime` is specifically UTC timezone, whereas `new Date()` is specifically *your* timezone.  It takes those both into account and gives you an accurate result.

Comment: Can you produce a snippet in your question that shows that the result is wrong (using the comparison you do in the `console.log`)? Use the toolbar in the editor.

Comment: @ trincot I did this ! didn't I?

Comment: Use the toolbar to turn this into a runnable snippet.

Comment: No, current time in *your local time zone* is 18:57:21, but that is not the UTC time right now. The `givenTime` is in UTC time. The output is correct.

Comment: Your `givenTime` (`2021-08-01T16:49:08.678Z`) is ahead of the current time... this will always be true until the given time is in the past... But you should probably compare using the timestamp as others have pointed out

Comment: I understand what You say, but I don't know how to convert my dates to be comparable?

Comment: That depends on what you expect? If you *intend* `givenTime` to be UTC time, then the comparison is currently correct. If you *intend* `givenTime` to be local time, even though it is formatted as zero time zone (`Z`), then you need to change that: remove the `T` and `Z` from that string and try again.

Comment: How about to use `getTime` ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to compare two local date/times.  In that case, don't specify one of them as being UTC.

```
// delete the Z
const givenTime = '2021-08-01T16:49:08.678';
```

Note that this snippet will only return "false" if it's currently later than 4:49 pm in your local time zone.  For me, it's not, so I get "true".

Also, `new Date(givenTime) > new Date` won't work.   I believe you mean `new Date(givenTime) > new Date(currentdate)` or `new Date(givenTime) > new Date()` - they are essentially the same.

```js
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var currentTime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                    + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                    + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                    + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                    + currentdate.getSeconds();
    
    
const givenTime = '2021-08-01T16:49:08.678';
    
// This is not comparing time , it only compares the dates
console.log(new Date(givenTime) > new Date(currentdate), currentTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert those Date objects to timestamp(number) first and then compare equality of them.

example

```
var timestamp_1970 = new Date(0).getTime(); // 1970-01-01 00:00:00
var timestamp = new Date().getTime(); // Current Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used this and it works perfectly without touching the givenTime:

```js
var currentTime =  new Date().toISOString();

console.log(currentTime)

const givenTime = '2021-08-01T14:13:08.678Z';

console.log(givenTime > currentTime);
```

Comment: You are doing a string comparison.  This will fail if givenTime is *not* in `Z`, now.

Comment: Why would you do this though?  If you want to compare local times then use local times.  If you want to compare both UTC then use both UTC.  If you want to compare one UTC and one local, then understand that even though it's 6pm where you are, it's only 2pm (eg) UTC.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to compare two dates is by using [UNIX timestamps](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).

Adding `.getTime()` after `const currentDate` converts the date object into a UNIX timestamp. UNIX timestamps are easily comparable. `const givenTime = new Date('2021-08-01T16:49:08.678Z').getTime();` also returns a UNIX timestamp, which you can then compare with the current time.